# How to load dynamic config in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to load dynamic values to initialize angularfire2 but it errors out when using aot.

```
let _env = {
        apiKey: 'key...',
        authDomain: dynamicValueFromConfig,
        databaseURL: 'url...',
        projectId: 'id...',
        storageBucket: 'bucket id...',
        messagingSenderId: 'messaging id...'

imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(_env), // issue here
    ...
```

This is a known issue and there are some answers for older versions:
[AngularFire2 App Init in Module Conflicts with Dynamic Config Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546529/angularfire2-app-init-in-module-conflicts-with-dynamic-config-data)

But I can't make it work with AngularFire v5... Angular 6 using Webpack.

Comment: can you a post a minimal working example of what you have using stackblitz?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `FirebaseOptionsToken` in the providers array.
Like this `{ provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: _env}`

More about this issue, [refer this](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1635).