# How do I refer to my config in my imports?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services, angular-dependency-injection, angular-config

I have added AngularFire to my project. In its readme I was instructed to add the `AngularFireModule.initializeApp(...)` to the imports of my `AppModule`

In examples people use the environment constant, however, that is not an option because Deployment requires that there be a config file where it would then substitute variables when it deploys depending on the environment it deploys to.

I believe my config is loaded after the imports which means nothing is passed to the `.initializeApp(...)`

#### app.module.ts

```js
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
...

export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  return () => appConfig.load();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(AppConfig.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AppConfig,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: initializeApp, deps: [AppConfig], multi: true },
    ...,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### app-config.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigModel } from './shared/models/app-config.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

/**
 * This config pattern based off https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-editable-config-files/
 * which is referenced in Octopus Deploy blog here https://octopus.com/blog/javascript-configuration
 */
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig extends AppConfigModel {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Loads the required config file from assets, depending on configName of environment.
   * This allows replacement of variables by Octopus Deploy
   */
  public load() {
    const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.configName}.json`;

    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: AppConfigModel) => {
        this.mapConfigToProperties(response);
        resolve();
      }).catch((response: any) => {
        console.error('On config load', response);
        reject(`Could not config load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
      });
    });
  }

  private mapConfigToProperties(config: any) {
    Object.keys(config).forEach(key => {
      AppConfig[key] = config[key];
    });
  }
}
```

I would very much like to get this solved without having to change any build processes and simply being able to to use the `AppConfig` to retrive the config.

#### package.json

```
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^7.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.16",
    "ng-pick-datetime-moment": "1.0.7",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.1.1",
    "ngx-textarea-autosize": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  ...
}
```

#### main.ts

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { FirebaseOptionsToken, AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers).

Comment: Turns out APP_INITIALIZER does not necessarily run before the `.initializeApp(...)` is called. If you see above there already is an APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: Doh... my bad. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by providing parameters to the `platformBrowserDynamic(...)` which takes an array of providers similar to the array in the `providers` property of `@NgModule`.

We will solve this by using this parameter. We will feed in the parameter for the firebase config and then remove it from the import in the AppModule.

#### main.ts

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { FirebaseOptionsToken, AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

// Get the config file
fetch(`assets/config/config.${environment.configName}.json`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((response: any) => {
    // Here we add the additional provider
    platformBrowserDynamic([{provide: FirebaseOptionsToken, useValue: response.firebaseSettings}])
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
}).catch((response: any) => {
  console.error('On config load', response);
});
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseOptionsToken } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
...

export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
  return () => appConfig.load();
}

// initialize app with empty config
const angularFireImport = AngularFireModule.initializeApp({});

// remove the provider that we have provided for in the platforBrowserDynamic
angularFireImport.providers = angularFireImport.providers.filter(
  (provider: any) => provider.provide !== FirebaseOptionsToken
);


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    // import the module we constructed above without the provider
    angularFireImport,
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ...,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This answer was inspired by [AngularFire2 App Init in Module Conflicts with Dynamic Config Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42546529/angularfire2-app-init-in-module-conflicts-with-dynamic-config-data)

Additional reading on providers and angular dependency injection, [link](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers)